# Input to processes (batch files)

Tags: c#, batch-file, input

I'm trying to make some kind of app, in C# Windows Forms Application (not console one, with tab pages, configuration, and console as a list box).

My problem is, that when I am writing some kind of input (to the text box), nothing happens (I'm new to coding).

My code:

```
Process process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = textBox2.Text,
                    //Arguments = textBox3.Text,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                }
            };
    server = process;
    process.Start();
    ...

/* LATER */

...
serverInput = process.StandardInput;
...
serverInput.Write(textBoxInput.Text);
```

**UPDATE - SOLVED**: code:

```
serverInput.WriteLine(...);
```

Comment: which process you are starting? what are possible values you input in `textBox2.Text`?

Comment: @HassanNisar You can insert anything to textBox2.Text (for now), but you should but there directory of the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1**:

This will be enough to run a batch files present in a directory:

```
string[] arrBatFiles = Directory.GetFiles(textBox2.Text, "*.bat"); //search at directory path

//loop through all batch files
foreach(string sFile in arrBatFiles)
{
   Process.Start(sFile);
}
```

**Method 2**:

If you want to use *ProcessStartInfo* members, use following method:

```
public void ExecuteCommand(string sBatchFile, string command)
{
    int ExitCode;
    ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
    Process process;
    string sBatchFilePath = textBox2.Text;  //batch file Path

    ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(sBatchFile, command);
    ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    ProcessInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(sBatchFile);
    // *** Redirect the output ***
    ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

    process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
    process.WaitForExit();

    // *** Read the streams ***
    string sInput = process.StardardInput.ReadToEnd();
    string sOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string sError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    ExitCode = process.ExitCode;
}
```

**UPDATE**:

How to call when you have directory of batch files.

```
string[] arrBatFiles = Directory.GetFiles(textBox2.Text, "*.bat"); //search at directory path

//loop through all batch files
foreach(string sFile in arrBatFiles)
{
   ExecuteCommand(sFile, string.Empty); //string.Empty refer optional command args
}
```

Comment: But how to execute command, while the process is already running ?

Comment: Which process already running? Something missing in your question. You have to call above method on some event like button click or form load.

Comment: When process Example1 (in this case say it is Windows cmd.exe) is running, how to execute a command ? (Ex. button click = input in to the process (programatically) ex. "help")